# htaccess rewrite index.php to .html

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have following rewriterules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^\-]*)-(.*)-von-(.*)\.html$ $1index.php?filter=$2&marke=$3 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^\-]*)-von-(.*)\.html$ $1index.php?marke=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^\-]*)-(.*)\.html$ $1index.php?filter=$2 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1index.php
```

The first 3 rules are working, but the fourth, just rewrite index.php to .html is not. What is wrong here?

EDIT:

The URL is example.com/folder/subfolder/index.php

In the folder I got following htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subfolder(.*) subfolder/$1
```

And the htaccess in subfolder is the one above

Now the URL for the first rule is example.com/folder/subfolder-value1-von-value2.html and works, for the second and third rule it's example.com/folder/subfolder-value1.html and example.com/folder/subfolder-von-value2.html
So with logic the fourth rule should also work just without the parameters but it's not working

Comment: Your 4th rule will rewrite `index.html` to `/indexindex.php` which doesn't make any sense. Clarify with examples what you're trying to do.

Comment: Allright I'll edit my post then you will see more

Comment: With RewriteRule ^(.*)html$ $1index.php so without the dot example.com/folder/subfolderhtml it works but I need the dot -.-

Comment: With 4th rule `example.com/folder/subfolder-value1-von-value2.html` will be rewritten to `example.com/folder/subfolder/value1-von-value2index.php` which will give you 404 since `value1-von-value2index.php` won't exist in subfolder.

Comment: But it's not because I get value1 and value2 correctly it goes to mysql_query and I get stuff associated with these values. I only get the forbidden error with fourth rule: example.com/folder/subfolder.html

Comment: `example.com/folder/subfolder.html` should rewrite to `example.com/folder/subfolder/index.php` add `[L,R]` flag to test in 4th rule

Comment: No not working. When I try RewriteRule ^(.*)html$ $1index.php so without the dot then example.com/folder/subfolderhtml rewrites to example.com/folder/subfolder/index.php and it works, but how can I make it work with the dot, it seems impossible

Comment: Did you add `[L,R]` flag to test in 4th rule?

Comment: well I guess the only way is to rename subfolder to subfolder. (with dot) then it works and edit the first 3 rules to it xD But I dont know how do edit the first 3 rules then

Comment: Yes i tryed but also get error

Comment: What URL do you see after redirect in your browser?

Comment: I dont get redirect, the URL example.com/folder/subfolder.html gives error: forbidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this in `/folder/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^subfolder\.html$ subfolder/index.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^subfolder(.+) subfolder/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: omg it WORKS THANK YOU =) hours of struggle are finally over :)

Comment: I have only one more question, what would be the rule when the subfolder name is subfolder-two so with a hyphen? I need a rule which works with and without hyphen

Comment: I am on mobile at present. I will update the rule in couple of hours.

Comment: That rule will be: `RewriteRule ^(subfolder-two)\.html$ $1/index.php [L,NC]`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't add `$1` to the second part of the rule.it'll append the first matching group to the `index.php` file name. what you are currently getting is 'indexindex.php'

if you just want to rewrite index.html to index.php then you can place following line at the end of the file.

```
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php [L,NC]
```

also you might wanna remove `$1` part from other lines as well.

Comment: no I don't want index.php to be index.html but just .html. I changed rewriterules for the folders where the index.php files are included so they work without / at the end and I get urls like example.com/folder-value1-von-value2.html it all works fine just not example.com/folder.html, so the last rule. It's not working when I leave $1 at any of the rules, also the fourth

Comment: @EddyUnruh As i said on my post, `$1index.php` translate to `example.com/folderindex.php` do you have a such file ? if you want to redirect `example.com/folder.html` to `exampl.com/folder` then you can use `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1`

Comment: Thats right it translates to example.com/folderindex.php and example.com/folderindex.php translates to example.com/folder/index.php because of the rules in root of the domain. It all works fine except the fourth rule, I just need to rewrite index.php to .html I don't know why it's working when parameters are set and not without

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this & see ?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1\.php
```

Comment: It makes index.php to index.html and works but I need index.php to just .html

Comment: what do u mean by just .html. It means it can be abc.html or bcd.html ? In that case u need to do it like this - RewriteRule ^abc\.html index\.php

Comment: no it means just .html and nothing before it because I allready use the folder name as category name

Comment: I guess it's impossible when nothing comes before .html?